# Ionic : How can I take a picture on a user device from my back end?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, background, backend, ionic-native

I want to achieve taking a picture in a ionic app from my backend.

I attempted to use `cordova-plugin-camera-preview` while hiding the given preview, without success.

Can anyone please advise on a good way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **create a cordova plugin** who would do that. It would still require the user to accept your app to have access to the camera though.

I guess you would have to make a **real-time backend** (using nodejs with socket.io for example). Then you would have to **retrieve the websockets** in the **background** of your app in a **service**, and then, in this service : use the **native camera API** to do what you want.

This way you could execute a function on your backend, **asking a specific user to take a picture** (even if the app isn't running) and to **send it back**.

**I didn't really look into it but you might have permissions issues at some point and you might end up being able to do it for an OS and not for another.** I would appreciate if anyone can confirm that.

Good luck!

> PS : This kind of feature present **ethical issues**. Do not forget to
>   **be honest** with your users about the real purpose of such a feature. **Respect** your users **privacy**.